# Raspberry Pi Zero W Connects to WiFi but Immediate Disconnects

Tags: wifi, wpa, wpa-supplicant

I've got a Pi0W. I've also got a WPA2 Enterprise Wi-Fi network set up with TTLS.
My other Pis (both Pi3B+) can connect with my current setup just fine.

The logs of my Pi0W are akind to the following:

```
Trying to associate with SSID 'MyWifiSsidName'
Associated with aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
...
eap auth logs
...
CTRL-EVENT-EAP-SUCCESS EAP authentication completed successfully
CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff completed [id=0 id_str=]
CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff reason=2 locally_generated=1
CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=GB
```

And then it tries again with the same pattern.
I see that the disconnected reason is 2, which apparently means "previous authentication no longer valid," but that has me scratching my head since it literally just authenticated, and that other Pis are having no issue with this setup.

It could potentially be due to the country codes? But I'm not sure why. All of my Wi-Fi related devices are set to GB (I've had issues using US with TTLS).

Any ideas?

Comment: what are you running on the zero?

Comment: The RPiZ model and others do not have real time clock (RTC) ... maybe a problem with your certificate and the current raspberry time? Check your system time.

Comment: @abolotnov As in what OS? Rasbian Lite (no UI). Software and services? Nothing additional, yet.

Comment: @Ephemeral why would the TTLS process succeed if that were the case? Wouldn't it fail before it finishes connection?

Comment: @Ephemeral I just updated the system clock to be recent and the same issue persists.

Comment: I have also taken out the variable of low Wi-Fi signal. I'm right next to the darn thing.

Comment: @TimMorris, can you use wireshark or other sniffer for see what's is done ? and have you try : `sudo iw reg set GB` ?

Comment: @TimMorris What is your version of Rasbian Lite ? have you try to reboot your Access Point also ?

Comment: @Ephemeral iw reg is already at GB, consistent with the other Pis. I tried updating Rasbian using dist-upgrade and it's now at 4.19.66+ (using uname -r). It's still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with Raspbian buster. It seens to be a bug related with nl80211 driver, wpa_supplicant regarding the connection with WPA enterprise ([link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/raspbian/+bug/1834749)). So if you are going through the same problem as me then these are the two solutions:

1. Change the driver used from nl80211 to wext;
2. Downgrade your current wpa_supplicant version;

In my case, I just changed the driver and the problem was solved.

Comment: I have no clue where this Pi Zero even is anymore. I may have bricked it. But I'm giving you the right answer in hopes it helps out anyone in the future who encounters this issue.